# Magento Collection values in Dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, drop-downs

I am using magento 1.9 version. 
I need to display customer groups in dropdown option.

I used [this](https://pastebin.com/qS7SfVcG) code.

It brings the data as dropdown.

My issue is When i use this code some css issues occurs.

By commenting the collection data (ie., `line# 4` to `line #6`) it's working fine.

what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<select class=" input-text custgroup required-entry" name="product[tier_price][<?php echo $i; ?>][cust_group]" id="tier_price_row_<?php echo $i;?>_cust_group">
        <option value=''>Select Customer Group</option>
        <option <?php if($tierPrice['cust_group']=='32000') echo 'selected = "selected"';?> value='32000'>ALL GROUPS</option>

        <?php
         $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
        foreach($customer as $type) :?>
        <option <?php if($tierPrice['cust_group'] == $type['customer_group_id']) {echo 'selected = selected"';}?> value="<?php echo $type->getCustomerGroupId();?>">
        <?php echo $type['customer_group_code']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

Comment: No luck. Same result. I think the issue in foreach only.